Eigenvalues of Powers of a Matrix
It is well known that if $A$ is a matrix with eigenvalue $\lambda$ that $A^n v = \lambda^n v$, where $v$ is the corresponding eigenvector. In other words, the eigenvalues of $A^n$ are those of $A$ raised to the $n$.
My question is about the converse of this in some sense. If $A^n$ has an eigenvalue $\lambda$, is it true that $\lambda^{1/n}$ is an eigenvalue of $A$? If so, is this how we obtain all the eigenvalues of $A$?
For sake of simplicity let us assume we are working over $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$.
If not, under which conditions will this hold?

"The eigenvalues of $A^n$ are those of $A$ raised to $n$". This isn't true in general! You need the field to be algebraically closed.

@Kandinskij: Got it, I have edited the question!

For a start, how do you define $λ^{1/n}$, given that $λ$ is possibly complex? For a trivial example, take the 1×1 matrix $(e^{2iπ/n})$. Raised to the power $n$, it becomes the 1×1 matrix $(1)$. But the matrix $(1)$ itself, raised to the power $n$, also gives $(1)$.

Working over $\mathbb{C}$, at least one of the $n$-th roots of $\lambda$ would be an eigenvalue of $A$, although I do not think you can say in general which one of them.

@RaulAlmuzara: How about over $\mathbb{R}$?

Over $\mathbb{R}$, $-I$ does not have real eigenvalues for any reasonable definition of $A^{1/n}$
